# Cannot execute command on separate website using curl or file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
erorr_reporting(E_ALL);
$ch=curl_init("https://remote.com/act/hook/id");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
exit();
```

it does not seem to be working with the remote site.

i also tried:

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
erorr_reporting(E_ALL);
file_get_contents("https://remote.com/act/hook/id");
exit();
```

when i go to the site `https://remote.com/act/hook/id` on a browser it works fine.

not sure whats wrong here

** UPDATE **

for curl it says ssl certificate expired.

Comment: What's the output are you getting?

Comment: "Not working" means what? Are you getting an error? Are you getting any response from this whatsoever? Can you reproduce this with `curl` on the command-line?

Comment: @tadman im not getting any response from file_get_contents but curl is saying expired cefrtificate

Comment: Use `curl -i` to see the response header. You may be getting a rejection from that API in the form of a 4xx error. You can use `-k` to ignore the busted certificate.

Comment: Well, then use these options `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false)` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)`. And modify `$result = curl_exec($ch);` then `var_dump($result)`. Show us then what it returns.

Comment: @tadman that solved it thanks

Comment: If that's the case then unclexo has a solution for you, but the real solution is to poke the site owner and tell them to fix their busted cert.